# SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
 viewInvoiceByDate: (params, callBack) => {
    let startDate=params.date
    let endsDate=params.endDate
    
    startDate == "''" &&  startDate= new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    endsDate=="''"&& endsDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    pool.query(
      `SELECT * FROM cash_management WHERE date BETWEEN ${startDate} AND ${endsDate} `,
      (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          return callBack(error);
        }
        return callBack(null, results);
      }
    );
  },
```

SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1049:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (D:\AAA New\awakaza-pos-main-web-back-end\api\Cash\cashManagement.controller.js:1:43)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)

Comment: Something like `a == '' && a = 4` is not valid syntax, you can use the following instead: `a == '' && (a = 4)` (you need extra parentheses)

Comment: I would advise writing simpler code... `if (startDate === "''") startDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);`

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to check if startDate and endsDate are empty string and then assign current date to it?

Syntax below is not correct

```
startDate == "''" &&  startDate= new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
endsDate=="''"&& endsDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

Correct syntax could be

```
startDate === ' ' ? startDate= new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) : params.date;
```

use a conditional (ternary) Operator (?)

Comment: The comparison should be for `"''"`, not `' '`. You're also missing the `let` (or `const`) declarations